# Как запретить вводить минус после цифры в input

Tags: javascript, angular

Столкнулся со странной ситуацией, инпут дает возможность ввести "+" или "-" после числа, как такое можно побороть? Мне нужна возможность вводить отрицательные числа, но зачем есть возможность ставить знаки после числа не ясно как такое поправить подскажите пожалуйста идеи?

```
<input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="param.value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                       (change)="getPreviewDate(param)"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в какои браузере вы такое наблюдаете?

Comment: в гугл хроме такое поведение

Comment: Значит надо писать гуглу хрому, что вас такое не устраивает.  А можете добавить `pattern` с регулярным выражением, которое вам нужно.